# Dialogflow prevent repeating intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm bulding an agent with a lot of top level intents. Sometimes users ask a question which has not been added as an intent and it gets triggered by a wrong intent. Usually they try to ask the very same question again in a little different way. They get the same (wrong) intent again.

Is there a way I can avoid triggering the same intent multiple times in a row? It'd be cool to call the default fallback at the second time it is triggered. I'd like to apply this to all of the top level intents.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would achieve this without fulfillment is a little clunky, but it will do the job. All you do is for every top-level intent, create a duplicate (with the same training phrases), named something like `[original_intent_name]_repeat` and put a input context required of `[original_intent_name]_asked`. Then for all your original top-level intents, add an output context of `[original_intent_name]_asked` with a lifespan of `1`.

That way what happens is the following:

```
User: What's your name?
Bot: It's Dave! [intent `name`, output context `name_asked:1`
User: What's your name?
Bot: It appears you've already asked me my name! Try something else. [intent `name_repeat`]
```

This works because Dialogflow priorities intents with input context requirements over ones that do not.